# Discover wireless device from command line

Tags: wifi

Is there a command line option (or C#/Java library/solution) to list available WiFi devices just like what windows does: (On Windows 7, "Devices and Printers", then "Add a device" will list available devices available to be added to this computer"; I want to achieve the same on Windows XP and Windows 7).

I have found the Bluetooth equivalent [Bluetooth command line tools](http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/) and [32feet.NET](http://32feet.codeplex.com/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

In Linux you can use

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

This will give you the full details of all the scanned Access Points.

In C++ you can use the library libtins to perform the same operation and more.( http://libtins.github.io/)
Here is an example that servers your purpose - http://libtins.github.io/examples/beacon-display/